# JS added in bookmark still running after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

I'm running a JS code from a bookmark (on opera browser). I created an endless timer countdown which resfreshes my page every 10secs. It just fine in my .html file. But when i'm using it like a bookmark in any other site it works only 1 time and then it stops.

How could it be able to run after the refresh?

```
javascript: 
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;
function startTimer(secs) {
timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000); 
}
function tick( ) {
var secs = timeInSecs;
if (secs > 0) {
    timeInSecs--; 
}
else {
    location.assign(location.href.split('#')[0]);
    clearInterval(ticker);
    startTimer(1*10); 
}
}
startTimer(1*10);
```

Comment: I don't understand how your code is running, but if you run this in another page, when it refreshes your code is no longer embedded in the page

Comment: exactly , is it possible to be embedded somehow ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is creating a google chrome extension so that it will refresh the page for you after 10 secs, because what you are suggesting is injecting your own code into a website and that sounds like an XSS attack, even if your intentions aren't malicious

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an interval. As soon as you reload the page, the interval is cleared. As soon as the page is reloaded, your code executes again.

Try this instead:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = Math.random(); // Demonstrates the page reload

setTimeout(() => document.location.reload(), 1000);
```